# Exit cleanly from threads.

Tags: java, multithreading

There are many proxy servers. I should identify these servers that it can be used, or can't. The way of that is send `POST` request each proxies by using multiple threads. and then I pick up the server that replect to `200` http response code. Anyway, this is not emphasis of my question, I have to clear these threads because I should refresh proxy server every 30 minutes. Because the enviroment of public proxy server is very unstable. And I have to running this program all day long. (Sorry for awkward english)

I'm using this :

```
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
            Runnable r = new CheckProxy(ip[i], port[i]);
            new Thread(r).start();
        }
    }
```

There is web-site that showing proxy servers. I bring that, and push into above code. `CheckProxy` class do send post request, and save response code. Anyway In the conclusion, How can I exit these threads?

I tried this. made variable `static boolean isExit`, and method `public void stopChecking() { isExit = true; }`.

```
    if (!isExit){
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
            Runnable r = new CheckProxy(ip[i], port[i]);
            new Thread(r).start();
        }
    }
    else { Thread.interrupted(); }
}
```

What I'm going to do, just leave this threads. I want to quit all of threads that checking enable. In order to this, I called stopChecking(); however all of threads alive. What should I do?

Comment: You probably need to make `isExit` be `volatile` since it is being shared between threads.  Also, you should consider using an `ExecutorService` instead of forking your threads by hand.

Comment: huh? Thread.interrupted does nothing it checks a status. You actually have to interrupt the instances.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli So, how can I access by instance ? r.interrupted(); or Thread(r).interrupted ? is unable way... I don't know how to access instance...

Comment: @Gray Thanks to you, I learned `volatile` +1. Have a nice christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a List of Thread objects and then call join on them... like so,

```
java.util.List<Thread> al = new java.util.ArrayList<Thread>();
for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
  Runnable r = new CheckProxy(ip[i], port[i]);
  Thread t = new Thread(r);
  al.add(t);
  t.start();
}
// Ensure all of the threads finish before continuing.
for (Thread t : al) {
  t.join(); // or t.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a standard `ExecutorService` approach:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
    service.submit(new CheckProxy(ip[i], port[i]));
}

service.shutdown();
service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. I see that after accepting another question. It is very useful too thank you. have a nice chirstmas !